# cloudstack end-user cantg resize volumes

Tags: apache-cloudstack

End users (also Domain admins) can't resize Volumes - there is no such option in CS GUI (see img1.PNG) . While Cloudstack Admin is able resize vols (see img2.PNG).

Info: CS version - 4.8.0 HA management servers behind HAProxy with MariaDb Galera. Host: Xenserver.

img1.png:https://files.fm/u/krgxs9b9#/view/img1.PNG

img2.png: https://files.fm/u/krgxs9b9#/view/img2.PNG

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in 4.9 by the following PR. API allowed end users to resize but the option wasn't available through UI.
https://github.com/apache/cloudstack/pull/1595
In: /usr/share/cloudstack-management/webapps/client/scripts/storage.js

Removing:

`if (jsonObj.hypervisor == "KVM" || jsonObj.hypervisor == "XenServer" || jsonObj.hypervisor == "VMware") {
   if (jsonObj.state == "Ready" || jsonObj.state == "Allocated") {
         allowedActions.push("resize");
       }`

And adding:

```
if (jsonObj.state == "Ready" || jsonObj.state == "Allocated") {
      allowedActions.push("resize");
     }
```

Also removing: /usr/share/cloudstack-management/webapps/client/scripts/storage.js.gz

Resolves issue